# How to disable Facebook's "Add a Donate Button" on a shared post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

**Background:** I work for a crowdfunding website that collects donations on behalf of athletes to benefit nonprofits. Users of the website frequently share their campaigns to Facebook posts. The issue is Facebook recently started adding a "Add a Donate Button" to the top of the post which runs through their 3rd party donation system. This is not only confusing our users but potentially poaching them as well. We want the donations to flow through our site, not Facebook.

**What has been tried** I've tried creating an app through https://developer.facebook.com to see if there were any options of opting out of this feature but to no avail. We've also tried the sifting through the settings of the company page.

I believe Facebook is scraping keywords from the open graph tags to determine whether or not to show the "Add a Donate Button". **My question is: is there some open graph tag change I could make to prevent this behavior? Or, is there some configuration of the Facebook app that could prevent this.** I'd prefer not to change the text of the description or remove the nonprofit name as these are integral to the point of the application. Facebook's documentation on this is sparse at best.

Here is a sample of our Open Graph meta tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[FBAPPID]" />

<meta property="og:title" content="[PAGETITLE]" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="[CAMPAIGNURL]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="[PATHTOIMAGE]" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="[PATHTOIMAGE]" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="948" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="948" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Join us in supporting [NONPROFITNAME] by sponsoring [ATHLETENAME]. Click here to read [ATHLETENAME]'s story." />
```

Comment: Since, according to /help, charitable organizations must sign up for Facebook Payments before they can receive donations, I'd guess that is an issue of configuration of the according page rather than the specific URL or it meta data ...

Comment: @CBroe The company isn't really a charitable organization though, nor is their page configured as such on Facebook. They're more like GoFundMe. It seems more to me that Facebook's post scraping black box is a little overzealous in offering a donate button without considering the ramifications.

Comment: Can we have an actual example URL?

Comment: It gets worse: I've had my personal page for years, totally not an organization or anything, nor am I part of any such organizations (profit or non-profit), and have been seeing this button show up every time that I post for the past few weeks (maybe a month or two now).  It shouldn't be my page's configuration (which I've certainly not changed), and the posts themselves are general everyday topics.   :-(